# Python Nonnegative Linear Regression with t-values

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression, statsmodels

I must be missing something, but all I'm trying to do is run a basic linear regression with multiple variables. The catch is that the variables have custom bounds (some are 0 -> 1, others may be different). I want to see the coefficients of the solution complete with a `statsmodels.api`-like output of the t and P values.

I can run `statsmodels.api.OLS` with a `summary()`, but I can't seem to restrict the bounds of the variables to be nonnegative there.

I can run `scipy.optimize.nnls`, but that doesn't give me any output on the confidence of each variable.

I've also tried `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear` with the `bounds` parameter, but that doesn't seem to work at all the way I'd expect.

How can I combine these functions to get what I'm looking for? An example might be:

```
Ys = [1,2,3,4]
Xs = [[4,2,6,4], [6,2,1,4], [1,2,4,9]]
bounds = [[0,1], [0,1], [0,5], [0.2,0.4]]
```

Desired output:

```
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          1.3292      0.585     -2.274      0.024      -2.483      -0.176
x1             0.0184      0.010      1.859      0.065      -0.001       0.038
x2             0.0253      0.006      4.462      0.000       0.014       0.036
x3             0.0309      0.192      0.057      0.955      -0.368       0.390
```

With all the coefficients matching the bounds.

Comment: Added a solution using R's mle2 function as well as a solution based on the calculation of the information matrix on a log transformed Y scale...

Answer (score 1):

scipy has a special optimizer for this case, nnls.

The problem is that standard errors and inference are not standard and not easy to implement for the general case. (I haven't managed yet to figure out how to get standard errors.)

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1211

I used nnls in a case where I did not need standard errors and it works fine.

There is a second usecase for inequality or bounds constraints that are required during optimization where, however, the outcome is in general in the interior. Those cases can be handled by reparameterization and is used in several cases, e.g. log or logit link function for discrete or generalized linear models or for variance function estimation. If the optimum is in the interior, then standard inference applies.

**edit**

One way to get "approximate" standard errors is to find the parameters for the inequality constraint problem with an appropriate optimizer and then impose the constraints that turn out to be binding in estimating the standard model like OLS. For non-negativity constraints variables that have estimated parameters at the zero bound can just be dropped. That is, we treat the inequality constraints that are binding as equality constraints.

However, the computed standard errors in this case are under the **assumption** that we know which constraints are binding and do not take the uncertainty about inequality constraints that may or may not be binding into account.

Comment: I suppose the edit is a back-way around it. I was hoping for a more standard solution though. I assume R has a way to do this but it's surprising to me this isn't available in Python.

Comment: It's not surprising to me that it is not available in Python. AFAIK, Stata doesn't have it either. Non-standard cases like parameters that are possibly at the boundary of the parameter space are **tough** except in special cases. The distribution has mass points at the boundaries that are binding (or maybe close to binding). The literature for the general cases always looked to scary to me to try to implement it. (And it's not important enough to me to spend a month of my time on it.)

Answer (score 1):

If you would be OK using R I think you could also use `bbmle`'s `mle2` function to optimize the least squares likelihood function and calculate 95% confidence intervals on the nonnegative nnls coefficients. Furthermore, you can take into account that your coefficients cannot go negative by optimizing the log of your coefficients, so that on a backtransformed scale they could never become negative.

Here is a numerical example illustrating this approach, here in the context of deconvoluting a superposition of gaussian-shaped chromatographic peaks with Gaussian noise on them : (any comments welcome)

First let's simulate some data :

```
require(Matrix)
n = 200
x = 1:n
npeaks = 20
set.seed(123)
u = sample(x, npeaks, replace=FALSE) # peak locations which later need to be estimated
peakhrange = c(10,1E3) # peak height range
h = 10^runif(npeaks, min=log10(min(peakhrange)), max=log10(max(peakhrange))) # simulated peak heights, to be estimated
a = rep(0, n) # locations of spikes of simulated spike train, need to be estimated
a[u] = h
gauspeak = function(x, u, w, h=1) h*exp(((x-u)^2)/(-2*(w^2))) # shape of single peak, assumed to be known
bM = do.call(cbind, lapply(1:n, function (u) gauspeak(x, u=u, w=5, h=1) )) # banded matrix with theoretical peak shape function used
y_nonoise = as.vector(bM %*% a) # noiseless simulated signal = linear convolution of spike train with peak shape function
y = y_nonoise + rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=100) # simulated signal with gaussian noise on it
y = pmax(y,0)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(y, type="l", ylab="Signal", xlab="x", main="Simulated spike train (red) to be estimated given known blur kernel & with Gaussian noise")
lines(a, type="h", col="red")
```

[image]

Let's now deconvolute the measured noisy signal `y` with a banded matrix containing shifted copied of the known gaussian shaped blur kernel `bM` (this is our covariate/design matrix).

First, let's deconvolute the signal with nonnegative least squares :

```
library(nnls)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(a_nnls <- nnls(A=bM,b=y)$x) # 5.5 ms
plot(x, y, type="l", main="Ground truth (red), nnls estimate (blue)", ylab="Signal (black) & peaks (red & blue)", xlab="Time", ylim=c(-max(y),max(y)))
lines(x,-y)
lines(a, type="h", col="red", lwd=2)
lines(-a_nnls, type="h", col="blue", lwd=2)
yhat = as.vector(bM %*% a_nnls) # predicted values
residuals = (y-yhat)
nonzero = (a_nnls!=0) # nonzero coefficients
n = nrow(X)
p = sum(nonzero)+1 # nr of estimated parameters = nr of nonzero coefficients+estimated variance
variance = sum(residuals^2)/(n-p) # estimated variance = 8114.505
```

[image]

Now let's optimize the negative log-likelihood of our gaussian loss objective, and optimize the log of your coefficients so that on a backtransformed scale they can never be negative :

```
library(bbmle)
XM=as.matrix(bM)[,nonzero,drop=FALSE] # design matrix, keeping only covariates with nonnegative nnls coefs
colnames(XM)=paste0("v",as.character(1:n))[nonzero]
yv=as.vector(y) # response
# negative log likelihood function for gaussian loss
NEGLL_gaus_logbetas <- function(logbetas, X=XM, y=yv, sd=sqrt(variance)) {
  -sum(stats::dnorm(x = y, mean = X %*% exp(logbetas), sd = sd, log = TRUE))
}  
parnames(NEGLL_gaus_logbetas) <- colnames(XM)
system.time(fit <- mle2(
  minuslogl = NEGLL_gaus_logbetas, 
  start = setNames(log(a_nnls[nonzero]+1E-10), colnames(XM)), # we initialise with nnls estimates
  vecpar = TRUE,
  optimizer = "nlminb"
)) # takes 0.86s
AIC(fit) # 2394.857
summary(fit) # now gives log(coefficients) (note that p values are 2 sided)
# Coefficients:
#       Estimate Std. Error z value     Pr(z)    
# v10    4.57339    2.28665  2.0000 0.0454962 *  
# v11    5.30521    1.10127  4.8173 1.455e-06 ***
# v27    3.36162    1.37185  2.4504 0.0142689 *  
# v38    3.08328   23.98324  0.1286 0.8977059    
# v39    3.88101   12.01675  0.3230 0.7467206    
# v48    5.63771    3.33932  1.6883 0.0913571 .  
# v49    4.07475   16.21209  0.2513 0.8015511    
# v58    3.77749   19.78448  0.1909 0.8485789    
# v59    6.28745    1.53541  4.0950 4.222e-05 ***
# v70    1.23613  222.34992  0.0056 0.9955643    
# v71    2.67320   54.28789  0.0492 0.9607271    
# v80    5.54908    1.12656  4.9257 8.407e-07 ***
# v86    5.96813    9.31872  0.6404 0.5218830    
# v87    4.27829   84.86010  0.0504 0.9597911    
# v88    4.83853   21.42043  0.2259 0.8212918    
# v107   6.11318    0.64794  9.4348 < 2.2e-16 ***
# v108   4.13673    4.85345  0.8523 0.3940316    
# v117   3.27223    1.86578  1.7538 0.0794627 .  
# v129   4.48811    2.82435  1.5891 0.1120434    
# v130   4.79551    2.04481  2.3452 0.0190165 *  
# v145   3.97314    0.60547  6.5620 5.308e-11 ***
# v157   5.49003    0.13670 40.1608 < 2.2e-16 ***
# v172   5.88622    1.65908  3.5479 0.0003884 ***
# v173   6.49017    1.08156  6.0008 1.964e-09 ***
# v181   6.79913    1.81802  3.7399 0.0001841 ***
# v182   5.43450    7.66955  0.7086 0.4785848    
# v188   1.51878  233.81977  0.0065 0.9948174    
# v189   5.06634    5.20058  0.9742 0.3299632    
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# -2 log L: 2338.857 
exp(confint(fit, method="quad"))  # backtransformed confidence intervals calculated via quadratic approximation (=Wald confidence intervals)
#              2.5 %        97.5 %
# v10   1.095964e+00  8.562480e+03
# v11   2.326040e+01  1.743531e+03
# v27   1.959787e+00  4.242829e+02
# v38   8.403942e-20  5.670507e+21
# v39   2.863032e-09  8.206810e+11
# v48   4.036402e-01  1.953696e+05
# v49   9.330044e-13  3.710221e+15
# v58   6.309090e-16  3.027742e+18
# v59   2.652533e+01  1.090313e+04
# v70  1.871739e-189 6.330566e+189
# v71   8.933534e-46  2.349031e+47
# v80   2.824905e+01  2.338118e+03
# v86   4.568985e-06  3.342200e+10
# v87   4.216892e-71  1.233336e+74
# v88   7.383119e-17  2.159994e+20
# v107  1.268806e+02  1.608602e+03
# v108  4.626990e-03  8.468795e+05
# v117  6.806996e-01  1.021572e+03
# v129  3.508065e-01  2.255556e+04
# v130  2.198449e+00  6.655952e+03
# v145  1.622306e+01  1.741383e+02
# v157  1.853224e+02  3.167003e+02
# v172  1.393601e+01  9.301732e+03
# v173  7.907170e+01  5.486191e+03
# v181  2.542890e+01  3.164652e+04
# v182  6.789470e-05  7.735850e+08
# v188 4.284006e-199 4.867958e+199
# v189  5.936664e-03  4.236704e+06
library(broom)
signlevels = tidy(fit)$p.value/2 # 1-sided p values for peak to be sign higher than 1
adjsignlevels = p.adjust(signlevels, method="fdr") # FDR corrected p values
a_nnlsbbmle = exp(coef(fit)) # exp to backtransform
max(a_nnls[nonzero]-a_nnlsbbmle) # -9.981704e-11, coefficients as expected almost the same
plot(x, y, type="l", main="Ground truth (red), nnls bbmle logcoeff estimate (blue & green, green=FDR p value<0.05)", ylab="Signal (black) & peaks (red & blue)", xlab="Time", ylim=c(-max(y),max(y)))
lines(x,-y)
lines(a, type="h", col="red", lwd=2)
lines(x[nonzero], -a_nnlsbbmle, type="h", col="blue", lwd=2)
lines(x[nonzero][(adjsignlevels<0.05)&(a_nnlsbbmle>1)], -a_nnlsbbmle[(adjsignlevels<0.05)&(a_nnlsbbmle>1)], 
      type="h", col="green", lwd=2)
sum((signlevels<0.05)&(a_nnlsbbmle>1)) # 14 peaks significantly higher than 1 before FDR correction
sum((adjsignlevels<0.05)&(a_nnlsbbmle>1)) # 11 peaks significant after FDR correction
```

[image]

I haven't tried to compare the performance of this method relative to either nonparametric or parametric bootstrapping, but it's surely much faster.

I was also inclined to think that I should be able to calculate Wald confidence intervals for the nonnegative nnls coefficients based on the information matrix, calculated at a log transformed scale to enforce the nonnegativity constraints and evaluated at the nnls estimates.
I *think* this goes like this :

```
XM=as.matrix(bM)[,nonzero,drop=FALSE] # design matrix
posbetas = a_nnls[nonzero] # nonzero nnls coefficients
dispersion=sum(residuals^2)/(n-p) # estimated dispersion (variance in case of gaussian noise) (1 if noise were poisson or binomial)
information_matrix = t(XM) %*% XM # observed Fisher information matrix for nonzero coefs, ie negative of the 2nd derivative (Hessian) of the log likelihood at param estimates
scaled_information_matrix = (t(XM) %*% XM)*(1/dispersion) # information matrix scaled by 1/dispersion
# let's now calculate this scaled information matrix on a log transformed Y scale (cf. stat.psu.edu/~sesa/stat504/Lecture/lec2part2.pdf, slide 20 eqn 8 & Table 1) to take into account the nonnegativity constraints on the parameters
scaled_information_matrix_logscale = scaled_information_matrix/((1/posbetas)^2) # scaled information_matrix on transformed log scale=scaled information matrix/(PHI'(betas)^2) if PHI(beta)=log(beta)
vcov_logscale = solve(scaled_information_matrix_logscale) # scaled variance-covariance matrix of coefs on log scale ie of log(posbetas) # PS maybe figure out how to do this in better way using chol2inv & QR decomposition - in R unscaled covariance matrix is calculated as chol2inv(qr(XW_glm)$qr)
SEs_logscale = sqrt(diag(vcov_logscale)) # SEs of coefs on log scale ie of log(posbetas)
posbetas_LOWER95CL = exp(log(posbetas) - 1.96*SEs_logscale)
posbetas_UPPER95CL = exp(log(posbetas) + 1.96*SEs_logscale)
data.frame("2.5 %"=posbetas_LOWER95CL,"97.5 %"=posbetas_UPPER95CL,check.names=F)
#            2.5 %        97.5 %
# 1   1.095874e+00  8.563185e+03
# 2   2.325947e+01  1.743600e+03
# 3   1.959691e+00  4.243037e+02
# 4   8.397159e-20  5.675087e+21
# 5   2.861885e-09  8.210098e+11
# 6   4.036017e-01  1.953882e+05
# 7   9.325838e-13  3.711894e+15
# 8   6.306894e-16  3.028796e+18
# 9   2.652467e+01  1.090340e+04
# 10 1.870702e-189 6.334074e+189
# 11  8.932335e-46  2.349347e+47
# 12  2.824872e+01  2.338145e+03
# 13  4.568282e-06  3.342714e+10
# 14  4.210592e-71  1.235182e+74
# 15  7.380152e-17  2.160863e+20
# 16  1.268778e+02  1.608639e+03
# 17  4.626207e-03  8.470228e+05
# 18  6.806543e-01  1.021640e+03
# 19  3.507709e-01  2.255786e+04
# 20  2.198287e+00  6.656441e+03
# 21  1.622270e+01  1.741421e+02
# 22  1.853214e+02  3.167018e+02
# 23  1.393520e+01  9.302273e+03
# 24  7.906871e+01  5.486398e+03
# 25  2.542730e+01  3.164851e+04
# 26  6.787667e-05  7.737904e+08
# 27 4.249153e-199 4.907886e+199
# 28  5.935583e-03  4.237476e+06
z_logscale = log(posbetas)/SEs_logscale # z values for log(coefs) being greater than 0, ie coefs being > 1 (since log(1) = 0) 
pvals = pnorm(z_logscale, lower.tail=FALSE) # one-sided p values for log(coefs) being greater than 0, ie coefs being > 1 (since log(1) = 0)
pvals.adj = p.adjust(pvals, method="fdr") # FDR corrected p values

plot(x, y, type="l", main="Ground truth (red), nnls estimates (blue & green, green=FDR Wald p value<0.05)", ylab="Signal (black) & peaks (red & blue)", xlab="Time", ylim=c(-max(y),max(y)))
lines(x,-y)
lines(a, type="h", col="red", lwd=2)
lines(-a_nnls, type="h", col="blue", lwd=2)
lines(x[nonzero][pvals.adj<0.05], -a_nnls[nonzero][pvals.adj<0.05], 
      type="h", col="green", lwd=2)
sum((pvals<0.05)&(posbetas>1)) # 14 peaks significantly higher than 1 before FDR correction
sum((pvals.adj<0.05)&(posbetas>1)) # 11 peaks significantly higher than 1 after FDR correction
```

[image]

The results of these calculations and the ones returned by `mle2` are nearly identical (but much faster), so I think this is right, and would correspond that what we were implicitly doing with `mle2`...

Just refitting the covariates with positive coefficients in an `nnls` fit using a regular linear model fit btw does not work, since such a linear model fit would not take into account the nonnegativity constraints and so would result in nonsensical confidence intervals that could go negative.
This paper ["Exact post model selection inference for marginal screening" by Jason Lee & Jonathan Taylor](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5292-exact-post-model-selection-inference-for-marginal-screening.pdf) also presents a method to do post-model selection inference on nonnegative nnls (or LASSO) coefficients and uses truncated Gaussian distributions for that. I haven't seen any openly available implementation of this method for nnls fits though - for LASSO fits there is the [selectiveInference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/selectiveInference/index.html) package that does something like that. If anyone would happen to have an implementation, please let me know!